# Multiple instance of Selenium in flask

Tags: python, selenium, flask, flask-restful

I have these two endpoint:

```
@app.route('/api/v1/order', methods=['POST'])
def order():

        msg, return_data = bz.insertOrder()
        return msg, return_data


@app.route('/api/v1/offer', methods=['POST'])
def offer():
    msg, return_data = bz.insertOffer()
    return msg, return_data
```

Both functions call this, I strip some code lines:

```
def insertOrder():
    return scrape(1)


def insertOffer():
    return scrape(2)
```

And finally scrape function is this, again it is just a snipped:

```
def scrape(var):
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Safari()
        driver.get(login_url)
        elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "UserName")
        elem.clear()
        elem.send_keys(username)
        elemPwd = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Password")
        elemPwd.clear()
        elemPwd.send_keys(password)
        elemPwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(1)
        ....
        driver.get(logout_url)
        driver.close()
        return '', http.HTTPStatus.CREATED
    except:
       driver.get(logout_url)
       driver.close()
       return 'Internal server error', http.HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
```

I thounght to see multiple chrome browser open and close but as soon as I launch two post at the same time I got:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before
> assignment

Answer (score 0):

You may run multiple instances of chrome browser if you do call two different instances of it in your code. Your problem is you have only 1 driver declared but trying to involke the same driver

```
from selenium import webdriver

def scrape(var):
     drivers =  
 [webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\PATH\TO\DRIVER\chromedriver.exe'),  
 webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\PATH\TO\DRIVER\chromedriver.exe')]

     [Your Logic here]

     drivers[var].get("YourURL")
    
     [more Logic here]
```

you may run more instances by declaring more webdrivers inside your drivers array.